# Postgres Psycopg2 Create Table

Tags: python, database, postgresql, python-3.6, postgresql-10

I am new to Postgres and Python. I try to create a simple user table but I don't know why it isn't created.
The error message doesn't appear,

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import psycopg2
    
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(database = "projetofinal", user = "postgres", password = "admin", host = "localhost", port = "5432")
    except:
        print("I am unable to connect to the database") 
    
    cur = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE test (id serial PRIMARY KEY, num integer, data varchar);")
    except:
        print("I can't drop our test database!")
    
    conn.close()
    cur.close()
```

Any help or hint would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: There is no error message(s) in the DB logs?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You are forgetting to commit to the database!

```
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database = "projetofinal", user = "postgres", password = "admin", host = "localhost", port = "5432")
except:
    print("I am unable to connect to the database") 

cur = conn.cursor()
try:
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE test (id serial PRIMARY KEY, num integer, data varchar);")
except:
    print("I can't drop our test database!")

conn.commit() # <--- makes sure the change is shown in the database
conn.close()
cur.close()
```

`

Comment: Alternatively `conn.autocommit = True` before connection would do a job as well